# SQL - return records that match ALL inputs

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the structure below, where we have products, values/descriptors, categories of those values, and a few bridge tables. One bridge table is between Categories & Values, since categories can have many values, and values can belong to more than one category. CategoriesValues are essentially tags that can be assigned to products. Then have a products table, that has a product<->categoryvalues bridge table, called ProductsCategoryValue. Hopefully that makes sense.

The app needs to send in a list of tags (categoryvalueIDs), and I need to then return only products that match ALL of the CategoryValueIDs. In the following example I sent in tags (categoryvalueID) 4, 8, 20, and 71. I have a few products that have tag 4, a few that have tag 20. I have one product that has all four tags (4, 8, 20, 71). I only want to return that one product. But the code below gets products that match any.

This code returns products that match any of the values. I only want to return the product that matches all of the values. I feel like I'm missing something simple. Can someone help?

I am open to either (a) changing the table layout & model or (b) any query help against the current structure.

BTW this is in MySQL.

```
SELECT  p.ProductID,
    p.ProductName,
    p.ProductDescription,
    pv.CategoryValueID,
    cat.CategoryName,
    v.ValueString
FROM    Products cp
INNER JOIN ProductsCategoriesValues pcv
ON  p.ProductID = pcv.ProductID
INNER JOIN CategoriesValues cv
ON  pcv.CategoryValueID = cv.CategoryValueID
INNER JOIN Categories cat
ON  cat.CategoryID = cv.CategoryID
INNER JOIN `Values` v
ON  v.ValueID = cv.ValueID
WHERE   pcv.CategoryValueID IN (4,8,20,71)
ORDER BY ProductID, CategoryValueID
```

---

### Structure

```
CREATE TABLE `Products` (
  `ProductID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ProductName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ProductDescription` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  `Price` decimal(19,4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ProductID`)
) 

CREATE TABLE `Categories` (
  `CategoryID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CategoryName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `CategoryDescription` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CategoryUIOrder` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CategoryID`)
) 


CREATE TABLE `Values` (
  `ValueID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ValueString` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ValueID`)
) 


CREATE TABLE `CategoriesValues` (
  `CategoryValueID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CategoryID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ValueID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CategoryValueID`),
  KEY `FK_Values__Categories_idx` (`ValueID`),
  KEY `FK_Categories_Values_idx` (`CategoryID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Categories_Values` FOREIGN KEY (`CategoryID`) REFERENCES `Categories` (`CategoryID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Values_Categories` FOREIGN KEY (`ValueID`) REFERENCES `Values` (`ValueID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) 


CREATE TABLE `ProductsCategoriesValues` (
  `ProductID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CategoryValueID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ProductID`,`CategoryValueID`),
  KEY `FK_ProductsCategoryValues_Products` (`ProductID`),
  KEY `FK_ProductsCategoryValues_CategoryValue` (`CategoryValueID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ProductsCategoryValues_CategoryValue` FOREIGN KEY (`CategoryValueID`) REFERENCES `CategoriesValues` (`CategoryValueID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ProductsCategoryValues_Concepts` FOREIGN KEY (`ProductID`) REFERENCES `Products` (`ProductID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

EDIT----- adding sample data....

```
Products table
ProductsID, ProdName
1, Name1
2, Name2
3, Name3

Categories table
CategoryID, CategoryDescription
1, Cat1
2, Cat2
3, Cat3

Values table
ValueID, ValueDescription
1, Red
2, Blue
3, Green
4, Large
5, Small
6, New
7, Used
8, Tech
9, Toy
10, Fun

CategoriesValues Table
CategoryValueID, CategoryID, ValueID
1, 1, 1
…
4, 1, 1
…
8, 1, 3
…
20, 2, 9
…
71, 2, 10


ProductsCategoriesValues table
ProductID, CategoryValueID
1, 4
1, 8
1, 20
1, 71
2, 4
2, 8
3, 8
3, 20
4, 71

Desired output
1, 4
1, 8
1, 20
1, 71
```

Comment: Kindly share sample data and desired output

Comment: @zarruq Edited message to show sample data

Answer (score 1):

This is how to find product IDs in the `ProductsCategoriesValues` table, that match all four category values:

```
select productid
from productscategoriesvalues
where categoryvalueid in (4, 8, 20, 71)
group by productid
having count(*) = 4;
```

As you want to show products with categories and their values in your query, keep your query as is, but add this to its `WHERE` clause:

```
AND p.ProductID IN
(
  select productid
  from productscategoriesvalues
  where categoryvalueid in (4, 8, 20, 71)
  group by productid
  having count(*) = 4
)
```

Comment: If the list of categoryvalueid will vary (it may have 4 values, it may have 2, it may have 7, and so on) - will this still work? Would I put that list in a temp table and then join in this solution ^^ instead of using IN?

Comment: In above query there are four values and the number 4 for the count. Of Course if you change the criteria, you must keep this in mind. So if you change `in (4, 8, 20, 71)` to `in (2, 4, 6`) you must also change `count(*) = 4` to `count(*) = 3`. No big deal.

Comment: You can of course fill a temp table and thus have the query static if you like this better. `where categoryvalueid in (select val from temp) group by productid having count(*) = (select count(*) from temp)`.